# Which is exactly the main use of the "VS." label?

Tags: terminology

We have for this side, this order for a song name:

> *Song Name* (*Original Producer* **vs.** *Remixing Producer*)

For another side we this one with the remix label:

> *Original Producer* - *Song Name* (*Remixing Producer* **remix**)

Which is the exact difference?

It has something to do with the level of remixing? (i.e. a remix barely modified to fit more like to the remixer style, against another remix which substantially modified the original song)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*vs*, or *v*, meaning *versus*, is a way of giving two artists equal billing without implying that they wrote or performed the work together. It is therefore appropriate where one artist is a producer or remixer who has nevertheless had significant creative input into the final result, and would indeed suit cases where one artist's material has been modified to fit a remixer's style

A couple of examples:

[Bob Marley vs. Lee "Scratch" Perry: The Best of the Upsetter Years 1970-1971](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QZXTNY) - in this case, Lee Perry is the producer, but the marketing decision has been made to highlight his input.

[Massive Attack v Mad Professor - No Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Protection_(Massive_Attack_album)). This is a Remix album by Mad Professor of original Material by Massive Attack.

It is possible that the term originates partly from the reggae tradition of [Sound Clash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_clash), in which events might be billed as featuring one system 'vs' another.

Answer (score -1):

"vs" means "versus", in the meaning "against" or "in opposition to".  This is really a question about English language usage rather than music.  What the particular site intends to express in that manner I have no idea.  Presumably the remix may have a different name from the original, but labeling a single entry/category field in that manner does still not seem useful.

Possibly you are expected, when indeed those two differ, to enter both of them separated by `VS.` in the given order in a single field.

But that's entirely a stab in the dark.